# How to connect to AWS DocumentDB from Lambda function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ioexception, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect to `AWS` `DocumentDB` from a `C#` `Lambda` function.

The problem is that it `TLS` is enabled on `DocumentDB` and it requires me to add a certificate to a local store.

This is fine if I was running on an `EC2`, because it requires `READ/WRITE` access to the local file system.

Since I am running on a `Lambda`, I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

[Documentation that I've referenced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect.html#connect-tls-enabled).

I've tried the example code inside a Lambda and I get the following IOException (because it requires read/write access):

```
The X509 certificate could not be added to the store.: CryptographicException
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.DirectoryBasedStoreProvider.Add(ICertificatePal certPal)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Add(X509Certificate2 certificate)
at Lambdas.DependencyRegistar.ConfigureMongoDatabase() in /build_and_deploy/src/Lambdas/DependencyRegistar.cs:line 113
at Lambdas.DependencyRegistar.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /build_and_deploy/src/Lambdas/DependencyRegistar.cs:line 35
at Lambdas.Handlers.BaseLambdaHandler..ctor(IServiceCollection services) in /build_and_deploy/src/Lambdas/Handlers/BaseLambdaHandler.cs:line 36

--> Read-only file system: IOException <--
at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.DirectoryBasedStoreProvider.AddCertToStore(ICertificatePal certPal)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.DirectoryBasedStoreProvider.Add(ICertificatePal certPal)
```

The same code works fine locally on my windows machine (because I was able to successfully add the cert to my local store).

Comment: I was able to get around this by ignoring SSL validation:

var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));


            if (EnvironmentVariables.MongoDb.SSLEnabled)
            {
                settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings()
                {
                    CheckCertificateRevocation = false,
                    ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (o, c, ch, er) => true,
                };
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
            }

Comment: Valid question, and I'm surprised that there aren't that many good resources around importing a custom cert to a trust store in Lambda. Let me know if you find the right way to trust the cert, rather than suppressing the endpoint validation.

Comment: You might want to check that your Lambda is in a VPC with proper security groups that allows communication between the documentDb and Lambda.